# How to make 2 divs with 2 different backgrounds equal in height in when the height of one of them is set to auto and max height?

Tags: css, html

I've looked at 20 threads at least so far so sorry if this has been answered before but I couldn't find a solution that suits my particular css layout.

I want to set the height of 2 columns equal to each other in a way that the leftcolumn equals the contentcolumn. I've tried using multiple javascripts like this :
`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // get the heights
    l = $('#contentcolumn').height();

    // get maximum heights of all columns
    h = Math.max(l);

    // apply it
    $('#leftcolumn').height(h);
    });
```

And:

```
document.getElementById("leftcolumn").style.maxHeight = document.getElementById("contentcolumn").style.height;
```

And:

```
$("#contentcolumn").height($("#leftcolumn").height())
```

The problem with the first code is that it drops the left div to some really long height which I don't even know. The second and third codes change nothing at all.

Can someone please help me I know there's probably a really simple solution to this problem but I just can't find and I just can't go to sleep until I do !

New webpage after clean up:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="maincontainer">
<div id="topsection"></div>
<div id="leftcolumn"></div>
<div id="contentcolumn">
</div>
</font>
</body>
</html>
```

New CSS after clean up:

```
body,
html {
background: #cacaca url(img/bg.png) repeat-x;
}
#maincontainer {
width:1000px;
margin:0 auto;
background: url(img/bg5.png) repeat-x;
}
#topsection {
background: #ffffff url(img/bg4.png) repeat-y;
height: 10px;
}
#leftcolumn {
float:left;
height: 100%;
width: 145px;
background: url(img/bg2.png) repeat-y;
}
#contentcolumn {
margin-left: 145px; /*Set left margin to LeftColumnWidth*/
min-height: 800px;
height: auto;
background: #dbdbdb url(img/bg3.png) repeat-x;
padding:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without javascript--in a cross-browser way, even.  This takes advantage of absolutely-positioning elements within relatively-positioned elements.  If you set your #maincontainer div to `position: relative` and your #leftcolumn div to `position: absolute`, you can then set both `top` and `bottom` on #leftcolumn, so it always assumes the height of its parent (#maincontainer), even though #maincontiner's height is being set by its children (#contentcolumn in this case).  Use this [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PsSsm/) and play with #contentcolumn's height to see how #leftcolumn responds.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="maincontainer">
            <div id="topsection"></div>
            <div id="leftcolumn"></div>
            <div id="contentcolumn"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body,
html {
    background: #cacaca;
}

#maincontainer {
    position: relative;
    width:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background: #000;
}

#topsection {
    background: #ffffff;
    height: 10px;
}

#leftcolumn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px; /* room for #topsection */
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 145px;
    background: red;
}

#contentcolumn {
    margin-left: 145px; /*Set left margin to LeftColumnWidth*/
    min-height: 500px;
    height: auto;
    background: #dbdbdb;
    padding:10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked like a charm all I had to do was change the background tags and I was good to go Thanks a million =D